# python program freezes when appending elements to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing sort of a Numberama replica in command-line python as my first project. [This](https://en.pelala.net/numbri/) is a good example of the game I am trying to make.

```
from os import system, name

game = []

with open("default","r") as file:
    for line in file :
        #print(type(line))
        #line.strip('\n')
        for chr in line :
            if(chr!='\n'):
                game.append(int(chr))

print(game)

# clear screen
def clear() :
    # windows
    if (name == 'nt') :
        _ = system('cls')
    # linux/macOS
    else :
        _ = system('clear')

# check if game is won (everything is 0)
def win() :
    for n in game :
        if (n != 0) :
            return False
    return True

# display current board
def display() :
    clear()
    for pos in range(0,len(game)) :
        print(game[pos], end=' ')
        if((pos+1) % 9 == 0) :
            print('\n')

def add_numbers():
    for n in game :
        if(n) :
            game.append(n)

def input_pos() :
    pass
    return 0

def input_dir(pos) :
    pass
    return 0

def check_solve() :
    pass
    return True

while(win() == False) :
    # display board
    display()
    # check if there are possible pairs
    solve = check_solve()
    print("Type 'z' to add numbers.")
    if(solve) :
        print("Type 'x' to clear a pair")

    # input option
    opt = input('> ')
    if(opt == 'z'):
        add_numbers()
    elif(opt == 'x' and solve == True):
        pos1 = input_pos()
        pos2 = input_dir(pos1)
        if(game[pos1] == game[pos2] or game[pos1] + game[pos2] == 10) :
            game[pos1] = 0
            game[pos2] = 0
    elif(opt == 'q'):
        break

print('Thanks for playing Numberama!')
```

The `default` file stores the first three rows, like those in the example link.

Once I run the program, either in IDLE or through terminal (`python3 numberama.py`), and then type 'z' to "add numbers", the program just does nothing. I can still type but it still doesn't do anything.

In the command prompt, when I do 'ctrl+c' to stop python, this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numberama.py", line 69, in <module>
    add_numbers()
  File "numberama.py", line 43, in add_numbers
    game.append(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

After I type 'z' my cpu usage also skyrockets from 10%-ish to 30-50%, eventually spiking to 80% until I force-quit the program.

Comment: What do you think ``add_numbers`` does? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```py
def add_numbers():
    for n in game :
        if(n) :
            game.append(n)
```

You are appending items to the end of `game` as you loop through it - so you'll never reach the end. I'm not sure what you were intending to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
def add_numbers():
    for n in game :
        if(n) :
            game.append(n)
```

Appending items of game to game is never gonna end!(Hanged my pc:p)

**Instead you need this**

```py
    def add_numbers():
        nos = str(input("Enter nos > "))
        for n in nos:
             game.append(int(n))
```